# node.js redis synchronous solution

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis

I look for the package that allows to work with redis in synchronous manner. The problem is I don't want to rewrite the code for async flow.

The possible solution is

1. Find synchronous library to work with redis.
2. Implement a middle layer script in some synchronous language and communicate with this script by synchronous execution operation.

I tried to use [synchronize](https://github.com/alexeypetrushin/synchronize) with no success so far.

Comment: Did you try http://jxcore.com/pause-jump-and-continue/ ? You must be able to do it with a quick jump - contiune calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to give a try at [co](https://github.com/visionmedia/co), which will let you write non-blocking code using almost any existing node library. [Here](https://github.com/visionmedia/co/blob/master/examples/redis.js) is a specific example using node-redis.

Please note that co requires node 0.11.x (with `--harmony` flag) or 0.10.x with a wrapper like [gnode](https://github.com/TooTallNate/gnode).